# PHP: Is it bad practice to use an unset variable?

Tags: php, variables, unset

For example, if I want to use the code:

```
$foo = $_POST['foo']. $_GET['foo'];
```

to get a value whether passed by POST or GET, is this acceptable or bad practice?

Comment: obviously..Instead of that use $_REQUEST, will work for both..!!

Comment: ...as opposed to what?

Comment: It's a better idea to know whether the request is a POST or a GET in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see anything in your answer which is to be unsetted, though you can use `$_REQUEST['foo']`, as that will consider `$_POST` as well as `$_GET` but again, your code will be dirty, say for example I tweaked the `method` value, for login form, users can easily attack your website...

So be wise, use `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]` instead of using loose `$_REQUEST[]`

If for any means, you are using `$_REQUEST` thank make sure you use conditions to check whether the request is `GET` or `POST` using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Slick solution, but won't work properly when you POST `data` to `http://xxx/index.php?data=x`

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I was not aware of $_REQUEST.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Which of em will be accepted? the `$_POST['data']` or the `$_GET['data']` will be in `$_REQUEST['data']` ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien No. When you have GET and POST with the same variable, REQUEST is filled with the POST data!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
$foo = isset($_REQUEST['foo']) ? $_REQUEST['foo'] : null;
```

More at: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

to get value whether passeb by POS or GET use this

```
$foo = $_REQUEST['foo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your development server PHP to throw all warnings, you will find out.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using . operator, if i am not wrong this would concatenate the result, as the above suggested using $_REQUEST would be the better approach.

Comment: Was implying using concatenation on one existent variable and one non-existent variable to result in the existent variable only

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's terrible. There are two problems:

1. It will raise a warning
2. Concatenation is not suited for this use case

If you want to get a key from either `$_POST`, or `$_GET`, and you don't care which one the key is present in, you can use the $_REQUEST superglobal with the following idiom:

```
$var = isset($_REQUEST['foo']) ? $_REQUEST['foo'] : null;
```

`$_REQUEST` is the union of `$_GET` and `$_POST`.